# External Blog Embedded in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, routes

I have a wordpress blog on an EC2 instance. I want to make my app route from `myapp.com/blog` to go to my EC2 blog, but obviously with domain masking and full SEO value.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not save the hassle and go for blog.myapp.com?

Comment: You get a lot more SEO value if you don't do a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a setup with a web server like Apache or nginx I would configure this to proxy all requests in that path to your blog server. You then only have to care about proper caching in order to mitigate performance issues and not hitting two servers in every single request. It might be a good idea to load all assets directly for your blog server, not bothering your rails app server.

This might be harder when you have the default amazon setup relying on puma. You can still implement proxy-like behavior using a wildcard route and a controller fetching content from your blog server, but that does not really feel right....